# How to use Google Oauth2.0 to authenticate user via Telegram Bot

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client, python-telegram-bot

This is my first time interacting with Google API and I'm using python3.9 with this library [Python Telegram Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)
I want to access a user Google API Calendar via a telegram bot and I can't seem to find any article to guide me through it. My key problem (I think) is redirecting the success authorization flow back to telegram bot.

This is what I have in mind:

1. In the telegram app, user send '/send' to bot
2. Bot receive message and return a google an authorization link to user
3. User clink on authorization link and allow access
4. Bot receive authorization access and completes the Oauth flow

The problem lies betweeen step 3 and 4. A standard authorization link is
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=<clientid>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&scope=<scope>&state<state>&access_type=offline`

How do I send the authorization link back to my telegram bot? Should I create another API endpoint to receive that authorization link? Or can I send telegram api send_message() in the <redirect_uri> to redirect the success message to my bot.

**Update 1**

Thanks to CallMeStag, I manage to figure out a way to complete the oauth process. For people who faced the same problem, this is what I did
Pre-requisite: Credentials is created in google console api - Web application. redirect_uri set as localhost:8000 (During development phase)

1. User send '/send' to bot
2. Bot receive message and return an authorization link

   ```
   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=<clientid>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/&scope=<scope>&state<state>&access_type=offline
   ```
3. User click on link to authenticate and it will redirect to `http://localhost:8000`. Used fastapi as a webhook to receive the message. Capture the authorization code, use `google.oauthlib.flow` to complete the authorization process. Next, redirect user back to telegram link `https://t.me/<botname>`
4. Start using user google calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently indeed not very straight forward for a PTB-application to listen for external updates (the auth verification in this cas) - see also [this issue](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1258). Currently it might be easiest for you to set up a custom webhook application that runs in parallel to the `Updater` - e.g. using flask/django/starlette/fastapi/…. Alternatively, if you're using webhooks for your bot anyway, you can patch the `Updater` to do the job for you. Although that requires some manual work - see [here](https://github.com/jsmnbom/githubbotrevised/blob/master/bot/webhookupdater.py) for an example.

Once you are able to listen to updates coming from Google, handling them can be done via PTBs usual handler setup, specifically via the `TypeHandler` or even a custom `Handler` subclass - see this [FAQ entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#i-want-to-handle-updates-from-an-external-service-in-addition-to-the-telegram-updates-how-do-i-do-that).

Regarding the redirect url: You'll want to redirect your user back to your bot, so you'll have to provide a link that does that. [`Bot.link`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.link) should probably do the trick.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have been exploring based on your suggestion and I realized that I'll need an async function. I add a FastAPI to wait for an authorization code from user and I require my telegram bot functions to be async to complete the oauth authentication. How do I get about doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I see how asyncio comes into play. In any case, PTB currently does not support asyncio callbacks.